# Pidyon Haben with more than one Cohen

Tags: pidyon-haben

In this [article - שישה כוהנים פדו את הבנש"ק מבעלזא](http://www.bhol.co.il/news/983775) it describes (and has pictures) of the Pidyon Haben of the Belzer Rebbe's greatgrandchild being redeemed by **6 Cohanim**. They are even mentioned by name.

It seems from the pictures that all the Cohanim are doing the Pidyon simultaneously.

[image: 5 Cohanim drinking wine simultaneously]
Here they seem to be making the pre-ceremony הגפן simultaneously

[image: 5 Cohanim waving the coins simultaneously]
Here they seem to be waving the coins simultaneously

**Does anybody have details about how this is done?**

**E.g.: Is each Cohen given 5 coins? 
Or are the 5 coins divided between the Cohanim? (Is this even valid?)**

Comment: It could be in case any one of them isn't actually a Kohen

Comment: Does it have any relevance that they are in six?

Comment: They all look the same :->

Comment: @DoubleAA Your suspicion is discussed at length in the responsa of Machneh Ephraim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to question "Is this valid?":

Yes, it is valid. Nevertheless, it is a machlokes if it is *lechatchila* to distribute the 5 coins to numerous *Kohanim*.

Although the Gemara (Bechoros 51b, codified in [Shulchan Aruch Y"D 305:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.305.7?lang=he)) writes that even if distributed to ten *Kohanim* it works, the [Chasam Sofer (Shu"t §297](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Responsa_Chatam_Sofer%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.297.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), cited by [Pischei Teshuva YOD 305](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.305.7?lang=he&p2=Pithei_Teshuva_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.305.10&lang2=he)) paskens that this is *bedieved*.

Sources:
[Shulchan Aruch Y"D 305:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.305.7?lang=he)

> נתן ה' סלעים אפילו לעשרה כהנים בין בבת אחת בין בזה אחר זה בנו פדוי

[Chasam Sofer Shu"t §297](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Responsa_Chatam_Sofer%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.297.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)

> שלום לשר האלוף בינה והשכל הרבני המופלג תלמידי החביב מהו' מאיר ני' מבאסקאוויץ:‏
>
> לקחתי מעט פנאי להשיב בקיצור לעמוד על האמת בלי שום פלפול כי הזמן יקר וענין השליחות אינה נראה לי מה שאב שולח ממון לכהן על ידי שליח כי אין שליחות זה כקידושין וגטין דמלבד הגעת המעות להאשה צריך שיאמר ובעי' שיהיה אמירת השליח כאמירת הבעל ובגט אפי' טלי גיטך מעל גבי קרקע לא מהני ואי לאו דיד שליח כיד בע"הב אינה מגורשת אבל הכא לא יהא אלא מניח מעותיו על הקוף ומשלחו לכהן ויודיע שהוא שולח לו בפדיון בנו יי"ח מן התורה אין צריך לומר דבר רק שידע הכהן שבשביל פדיון נותן לו ואם כן מה לי הוא מה לי שלוחו אך הענין שהשליח נותן ממון של עצמו ואיננו מזכה ממונו להאב אלא רוצה לפדות בנו של פלוני בממון עצמו בשליחות פלוני ויהי' האב יי"ח פדיון מטעם שלוחו כמותו וכמי שמפריש מתבואות עצמו על כריו של פלוני ובהא פשיטא לשואל שבריב"ש דאינו נפדה על ידי שליח אבל ממון שלוח מבעלים לכהן אין זה פדיון על ידי שליח אלא הגעת ממון על ידי שליח ואין בכך כלום והרבה שגו בזה אמנם אם אין אב לפדות פודין הב"ד מממון של צבור את הבן והוא מ"ע בפ"ע:
>   והמזכה ה' סלעים לכהן על ידי שליח יי"ח ואינו דמיון לפטר חמור התם משהפריש תו אינו באחריותו מה שאין כן הכא חייב באחריותו אחר הפרשה עד שיקיים מצות נתינה או ליד כהן או ליד הזוכה בעבורו ושוב אין בע"הב חייב באחריותו למצות פדיון אלא באחריות המעות פי' אם הזוכה בשבילו פושע חייב הוא באחריותו ככל נפקד ואם אין לו לשלם ובע"הב פשע שמסרו לזה חייב הבע"הב באחריות לא ממצות פדיון שכבר בנו פדוי אלא ככל אחריות ממון של חברו שפושע בו:‏
>
> ומ"ש מתוס' ספ"ק דגיטין דע דמתנת כהונה כיון שאמר אפי' שלא בפניו שרוצה ליתן לכהן פלוני אינו יכול לחזור בו דהוה מתנה מועטת כיון שאין לו בו אלא ט"ה שוב ממילא אין יכול לחזור בו בלא דין דהולך כזכי ועיין מרדכי פ"ג דגיטין ולפע"ד נ"ל **דאין יכול לכתחלה לחלק ה' סלעים לב' כהנים** דכל שניתנה בו תורה שיעור אם מחלקו ה"ל חצי שיעור אף על גב דבדיעבד יוצא על ידי צירוף מ"מ מצוה מן המובחר לאכול השיעור בבת אחת או ליתן שיעור נתינתו בב"א:‏
>
> פ"ב נגהי ליום עש"ק בטוב שבט קפז"ל. משה"ק סופר מפפ"דמ.‏

[Pischei Teshuva YOD 305](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.305.7?lang=he&p2=Pithei_Teshuva_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.305.10&lang2=he)

> **בנו פדוי**. עיין בחכמת אדם כלל ק"נ דין ב' שכתב דאף דמלשון הגמרא והפוסקים שכתבו יצא משמע דלכתחלה לא יעשה כן נראה דלאו דוקא הוא דלא יהא אלא שאר מתנות כהונה [לעיל סימן ס"א סעיף ט'] וכתב עוד שדעת הפרישה בשם רש"ל דלכהן אחד צריך ליתן בבת אחת ע"ש [וע' בת' חתם סופר ס"ס רצ"ז שכתב וז"ל ונ"ל דאין יכול לכתחלה לחלק ה' סלעים לב' כהנים דכל שנתנה בו תורה שיעור אם מחלקו הו"ל חצי שיעור אע"ג דבדיעבד יוצא ע"י צרוף מ"מ מצוה מן המובחר לאכול השיעור בב"א או ליתן שיעור נתינתו בב"א עכ"ל ולא ידעתי מה יענה בהא דסי' ס"א הנ"ל דמבואר דאין קפידא רק בכדי נתינה ולא בהשיעור]:‏